# How to test my website compatibility on windows tablet

Tags: windows, tablet, simulator

I have made a Web Application on MVC4 Razor using c#. I have to make my application compatible with tablets running different OS like IPad, Android and Windows 8 or 8.1 on their browser (safari, chrome etc installed on those tablets)

I am using VS2012 and windows 7.

Someone, please tell me any simulator or emulator (dont know the difference) available as desktop version for windows 7 to test my application on tablet's browser.

As buying all these tablet is not possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a quick look and got a list of software [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/6-free-mobile-device-emulators-for-testing-your-site/). Not sure if they will suit your needs for a windows tablet, but there's **a lot** of links on google to other OS emulating software.

Comment: can you tell me specific emulator for Windows tablet only..?? As for android and iphone i also know lots of options.

Comment: Sorry, I just had a look but I can only find Windows Phone emulators :( if it works on Windows 7 Google Chrome on your computer, it's highly unlikely for it to not work on the windows tablets though (from experience using one)

Comment: Here you go http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: remember to green tick mark the question as answered if that's all you need, so the question isn't left open